# Spring-kafka Record offset commit time for Async manual commits

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring kafka based listener that receives a batch, processes and then manually acknowledges it as in the code below:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = my_topic)
    public void consume(@Payload List<String> messages,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    for (String message: messages) {
         // process each message
    }
    // Ideally the timer will record start time here
    acknowledgement.acknowledge();
```

My config class has the commit callback logic. I would like to record a timer for the time between when the acknowledge is called and when the callback is received.

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        log.info("Creating kafka listener factory");
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory
                = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(false);     
        factory.getContainerProperties()
                .setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        // More config
        factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitCallback((map, ex) -> {
        // Ideally the end time will be recorded here and timer metric published.
            if (ex == null) {
                log.info("Successful commit for {}", map);
            } else {
                log.error("Commit failed for {} with exception: {}", map, ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I do it with spring kafka? The acknowledge method doesn't let me pass any values to refer in the callback.

Comment: What's the version of spring-kafka ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add metadata to the `OffsetAndMetadata` by configuring an `OffsetAndMetadataProvider`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#offsetAndMetadataProvider

It is called for each offset that will be committed.

```java
/**
 * Provider for {@link OffsetAndMetadata}. The provider can be used to have more granularity when creating an
 * {@link OffsetAndMetadata}. The provider is used for both sync and async commits of the offsets.
 *
 * @author Francois Rosiere
 * @since 2.8.5
 * @see org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetCommitCallback
 */
public interface OffsetAndMetadataProvider {

    /**
     * Provide an offset and metadata object for the given listener metadata and offset.
     *
     * @param listenerMetadata metadata associated to a listener.
     * @param offset an offset.
     * @return an offset and metadata.
     */
    OffsetAndMetadata provide(ListenerMetadata listenerMetadata, long offset);
}
```